# How to compute using SQL for a specific row

Tags: sql

**Sample table:**

```
Metric     Value
Actual      10
Forecast    15
Target      12
```

I want to compute the metric as   sum of actual + forecast divided by target.
Can you help if this is possible in SQL.

Comment: What do you trying so far? Please, follow the [recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chanses for getting an answer.

Comment: What is the table structure? Do you have Metric and Value as the two columns of the table or is it one row in your example with 3 fields called: Actual, Forecast and Target?

Comment: The definition of the table, as you present it, prevents any meaningful answer. Is it a table with 3 values per row (i.e. Actual, Forecast and Target) or it has two columns as shown? If two columns (and I assume you have many **SETS** like the above), how do you select the relevant three values?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your data is in multiple rows.  You can "pivot" the data in several ways.  One is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select (sum(case when metric = 'actual' then value else 0 end) +
        sum(case when metric = 'forecast' then value else 0 end)
       ) / sum(case when metric = 'target' then value end)
from t;
```